# How do I change my DNS Zone record?

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to point the sub-domain analytics.xsitegroup.ca to 72.38.66.14:82

I am currently in the xsitegroup.ca's hosting control pannel's DNS Zone Editor, and here is the relevant line:

```
analytics.xsitegroup.ca.    14400   IN  CNAME   72.38.66.14
```

How do I set this up?

Comment: A DNS entry does not contain a port number; what you're asking can't be done.

Comment: A SRV record  can, but that doesn't help ;)

Comment: I was going to use port forwarding on the target server to achieve the same thing.  It's worth a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really provide enough information but it looks like whatever DNS provider it is uses the bind zone file syntax. You've also included a port in the IP address which you can't configure in any DNS system.

There are several different types of records in DNS zones, when you're associating a name to an IP address you need to use an 'A' type record. 'CNAME' records are like aliases to an already defined name (and can be another A record or a CNAME record, it can point at a different domain if you'd like).

Your example is using a CNAME record but it's close. Changing it too an A record like the following should work:

```
analytics.xsitegroup.ca.    14400   IN  A   72.38.66.14
```

You'll then be able to access the panel using the following URL: http://analytics.xsitegroup.ca:82

Comment: One thing to note, that number '14400' is the length of time a record will be cached in seconds. If it was a valid record before it'll take up to 12 hours to take effect. There is also a TTL value on the zone file itself which may effect it.

Comment: Make sure you increment the zone's serial number for it to take effect if your DNS panel doesn't do this automatically. Most (good) ones do.